# What is the origin of がち in 病気がち?

Tags: etymology

I know from my dictionary that 病気がち means "proneness to being ill". 病気 just means illness, so where does the がち come from?

My research so far: I think がち might be the ます-stem of the verb 勝つ. The dictionary supports this hypothesis as it lists 勝ち as a suffix meaning "apt to do; tend to do (used to describe a negative tendency)". It also lists 涙勝ち as an "archaism" for "prone to crying" which further supports my hypothesis.

I have the following questions:

1. Is 勝つ really the origin of がち in 病気がち?
2. Why is a very **positive** verb such as 勝つ used to describe "being prone to something" in a **negative** way?
3. Are there any other examples of 勝つ being used in a negative way?
4. Are there any similar commonly used words ending in 勝ち?

Comment: Kenkyusha's NJED (4th ed.) may answer your first two questions, at least partly: 病気がちの sickly, weak, invalid, inclined to ill health. ～勝ち be apt to, be prone to, tend to, easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is 勝つ really the origin of がち in 病気がち?

Yes I think so. But in modern Japanese this suffix is usually written in hiragana.

> 2. Why is a very positive verb such as 勝つ used to describe "being prone to something" in a negative way?

In modern Japanese it mainly means *to win*, but 勝つ also means *to outweigh* or *to outperform*. Such ～がち suffix survives mainly in some fixed phrases. I think ～がち is not necessarily negative, as seen in the examples below.

> 3. Are there any other examples of 勝つ being used in a negative way?
> 4. Are there any similar commonly used words ending in 勝ち?

Here are some common phrases that are safely usable in modern Japanese.

- [～しがち](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%97%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A1%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B): (na-adj) *tend to do ～* (perhaps this is the most common example)
- ありがち: (na-adj) *common*, *frequently seen* (it does not have negative connotations)
- 荷が勝つ: (idiom) *～ is too much load* (for someone)
- 伏し目がち: (na-adj) *with eyes downcast*
- 赤みがかった(色)/青みがかった(色): *reddish/blueish (color)*

Theoretically, I think がち can be used with any action verbs, and you can find some examples in [this list](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/42286/example/m0u/%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A1/) (note that these are from relatively old novels). But がち sounds fairly literary today if used outside of fixed phrases.

Comment: 赤みがかる isn't a usage of 勝つ, is it?

Comment: @nodakai Hmm, I'm seeing two different explanations. http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/12054/meaning/m0u/ and http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/37976/meaning/m0u/ But 赤み**の**かった色 sounds okay to me, too, which implies the verb かつ is used here.

Comment: 「赤みがかった」は終止形にすると「赤みがかる」になります。この「がかる」はおそらく「掛かる」の連濁から来ているのではないでしょうか。一方で「赤みのかった」の終止形は「赤みがかつ」で、この「かつ」は「勝つ」から来ています。こちらの「の」「が」は助詞ですね。意味的にも「赤が他の色に覆いかぶさったもの」と「赤の成分が全体の中で突出しているもの」で違いがあるように思います。「赤みがかった青」とはいえますが「赤みの勝った青」とはいえませんよね。

Comment: @marasai 「赤みの勝った紫」という例が[リンク先](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/12054/meaning/m0u/)にあり、個人的にはこれは自然な表現のような気がします（もちろん普通はかなで書きますが、それを除けば）。Googleでも同様の用例がヒットします。勿論「神がかった声」とかは「かかる（懸かる）」だと思います（「神のかった声」は聞いたことがない）。

Comment: 「赤味の勝った紫」は紫が赤の成分を含むために成立する表現です。青は赤の成分を含まないために「赤味の勝った青」とはいえません。

Comment: @marasai ああそういう意味ですか。じゃあ「～（が／の）勝った」「～懸かった」の両方があって、ちょっと意味が違う、ということですかね。

Comment: そのとおりです。また、一般に「赤みがかった」や「青みがかった」と表現する場合は、そのほとんどが「かかる」だと思います。なお、手元にある共同通信記者ハンドブックには「かかる」の「以下は慣用で平仮名書き」の項目に「紫がかった色」という用例があります。

Comment: @marasai うーん個人的には「赤みがかった」と「赤みのかった」で意味の違いは全く感じないです。ググっても「グレーのかった青」「紫のかった青」みたいなのが多く、私の感覚と同様の使われ方をしている気がします。まあ個人的な印象だけですけど。

Comment: I wonder if かち is moreso the かつ in やがて...