# what's the meaning of 見勝ち？

Tags: meaning, words

I found this word in one of the Akutagawa Ryūnosuke's short stories called 夢.  the story begins like this:

> わたしはすっかり疲れていた。肩や頸の凝るのは勿論、不眠症もかなり甚しかった。のみならず偶々眠ったと思うと、いろいろの夢を見勝ちだった

Comment: Welcome to JLSE!  To avoid getting your question closed, will you please include your understanding of the phrase in question?  See: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/22352

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42587/5010

Answer (score 2):

It's 見る + がち. It is normally seen in its kana form, but here the author chose kanji, 勝ち. がち attached to a verb's stem means "apt/tend/prone to doing."